# Javascript: Use case for 'static members'

Tags: javascript, static, prototype, instance

The differences between 'instance members' and shared 'class' members are obvious to me, as are the times to use one or the other. But I've recently come across the concept of 'static members', which in Javascript are simply methods / properties on the constructor itself, unavailable to any instances via `this`. For clarity's sake, here's what I'm talking about:

```
var Constructor = function() {

  // Private instance members
  var private = 'I am private';

  // Public instance members
  this.public = 'I am public';

};

// Shared class members
Constructor.prototype.shared = 'I am shared';

// So-called 'static' member
Constructor.static = 'I am static';

var f = new Constructor();
f.private; // undefined
f.public; // 'I am public'
f.shared; // 'I am shared'
f.static; // undefined
```

Like I said, the purpose of and delineation between the first three are obvious. When, however, should one use static members? When is `Foo.bar()` ever better than just making it a shared method of the class: `Foo.prototype.bar()`?

I understand the prototype chain, so the obvious difference is that static members aren't part of the prototype chain of the instances -- which I guess may matter in some applications. But that's not the question. The question is, what is one (or more) good, real-world examples for creating such 'static members'?

Comment: The obvious difference is that static methods don't need an instance. Yes you could add it to the prototype and not use `this`, but it just makes things confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is one (or more) good, real-world examples for creating such 'static members'?

There are some good examples in the language itself. For example (there are a lot more than these two as well):

```
Array.isArray([]); // true
Object.keys(someObj); // Returns array of key identifiers
```

Static properties are useful for providing functionality associated with a "type" (array or object in the examples above) that doesn't depend on an instance.

Comment: Let's approach instances of custom constructors as a unique 'type' then (yeah, they're not, they're objects, but ignoring that). You have `MyAwesomeType` and want a method `.isAwesome()` that accepts a supposed instance and checks its validity. What are the ramifications of doing `MyAwesomeType.prototype.isAwesome()` rather than `MyAwesomeType.isAwesome()`? Are there problems with that implementation, or is it more a matter of separation of functionality (just like class-shared and instance-specific are separated, even though class-shared _could_ be instance-specific)?

Comment: If you have `X.prototype.isX()` it's a bit redundant... you can only invoke it on objects that are an `X` or they wouldn't have access to the method. You'd have to do `X.prototype.isX.call(Y)` to invoke it in the context of something that isn't an `X`. By using a static property you can do `X.isX(Y)` which makes a lot more sense. But yeah you could make it a property of the prototype if you want. It's just not very intuitive.

Comment: That clears matters up in my head a lot, thank you! An obvious explanation to a simple matter.... but apparently I just needed it overtly stated. Hopefully someone else finds this noob question useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Static properties are good for when you need a value that is common among all instances of the object. As a trivial example, you could have `Constructor.numberOfTimesInstantiated` which you increment by one each time `new Constructor` is called.